# Make can't find unistd.h although it's present

Tags: c, cmake

I'm trying to compile http_load inside an alpine docker image.

here is the dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.5

RUN apk update && apk add wget make gcc linux-headers

WORKDIR /home
RUN wget http://acme.com/software/http_load/http_load-12mar2006.tar.gz && tar xzf http_load-12mar2006.tar.gz

WORKDIR /home/http_load-12mar2006
RUN make
```

I get this error:

```
http_load.c:28:20: fatal error: unistd.h: No such file or directory
 #include <unistd.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:32: http_load.o] Error 1
```

I though linux-headers should contain this dependency, and indeed, I can find it here:

```
/home/http_load-12mar2006 # ls -l /usr/include/linux/unistd.h 
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           157 Oct 25  2016 /usr/include/linux/unistd.h
```

What is causing this error and how to fix it?

Comment: `linux-headers` is for kernel headers. You are probably missing a libc devel package.

Comment: tried it, it then fails to the next line "include <stdlib.h>". I'd rather not modify those source files I don't own cause i'm trying to make this dockerfile works with the original source tarball.

Comment: @Mat you're righ, I was missing `apk add libc-dev`. Now all headers files are properly included and the compiling works, thanks !

Comment: @Mat, if you want to make your comment into and answer, I'd validate it